# How to call a function that returns multiple rows and columns in a data.table?

Tags: r, statistics, data.table

I want to call a function inside a data.table that calculates a set of summary statistics like the following:

```
summ.stats <- function(vec) {
    list(
         Min = min(vec),
         Mean = mean(vec),
         S.D. = sd(vec),
         Median = median(vec),
         Max = max(vec))
}
```

and I want to call it in the `j` of a `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),b=c(1,4,3,2,1,4),c=c(2,3,4,5,2,1))

DT[, summ.stats(b), by=a]
```

This is fine and I get:

```
   a Min Mean      S.D. Median Max
1: 1   1  1.5 0.7071068    1.5   2
2: 2   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
3: 3   3  3.5 0.7071068    3.5   4
```

But I am interested in passing multiple variables to summ.stats. For example:

```
DT[, summ.stats(b, c), by=a]
```

I want to get something like:

```
   a Var Min Mean      S.D. Median Max
1: 1   b   1  1.5 0.7071068    1.5   2
2: 2   b   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
3: 3   b   3  3.5 0.7071068    3.5   4
4: 1   c   2  3.5 2.1213203    3.5   5
5: 2   c   2  2.5 0.7071068    2.5   3
6: 3   c   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively you can modify your function as follows:

```
summ.stats <- function(vec) {
    list(
        Var = names(vec),
         Min = sapply(vec, min),
         Mean = sapply(vec, mean),
         S.D. = sapply(vec, sd),
         Median = sapply(vec, median),
         Max = sapply(vec, max))
}

DT[, summ.stats(.SD), by=a] # no need for as.list(.SD) as Roger mentions
   a Var Min Mean      S.D. Median Max
1: 1   b   1  1.5 0.7071068    1.5   2
2: 1   c   2  3.5 2.1213203    3.5   5
3: 2   b   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
4: 2   c   2  2.5 0.7071068    2.5   3
5: 3   b   3  3.5 0.7071068    3.5   4
6: 3   c   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution, and more in line of what I was expecting. But I guess we can remove the `as.list` function, no?

Comment: @RogerBill, yes you're right. `sapply` or `lapply` internally converts to `list` first.

Answer (score 3):

Without explicitly reshaping to long form, you could do something like

```
rbindlist(lapply(c('b','c'), function(x) data.table(var = x, DT[,summ.stats(get(x)),by=a])))



#    var a Min Mean      S.D. Median Max
# 1:   b 1   1  1.5 0.7071068    1.5   2
# 2:   b 2   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
# 3:   b 3   3  3.5 0.7071068    3.5   4
# 4:   c 1   2  3.5 2.1213203    3.5   5
# 5:   c 2   2  2.5 0.7071068    2.5   3
# 6:   c 3   1  2.5 2.1213203    2.5   4
```

If you `reshape` the data to long form

```
reshape(DT, direction = 'long', 
            varying = list(value = c('b','c')), 
            times = c('b','c'))[,summ.stats(b), by = list(a, Var = time)]
```

will work as well.

---

Less efficiently you could use `ldply`from plyr, with a slight redefinition of the function

```
summ.stats2 <- function(vec) {
    data.table(
         Min = min(vec),
         Mean = mean(vec),
         S.D. = sd(vec),
         Median = median(vec),
         Max = max(vec))
}
library(plyr)
DT[, ldply(lapply(.SD, summ.stats2)),by =a]
```

Comment: Thanks. But with this approach I will get two columns (b and c) and not 5 columns (Min, Mean, S.D., Median and Max). I want as many columns as the ones returned by the function `summ.stats`. Is there a way to 'transpose' these sub-matrices?